# adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() without changing current view

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to add views to a `ViewPager` (by adding data and calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` on its `PagerAdapter`) without changing the view currently being displayed?

I want the dataset to update in the background while the user is viewing other views. My problem now is that, when it finishes updating, it goes back to displaying the initial view. How can I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know if you call notifyDatasetChanged() it only notifies the pager adapter that there is new data, the data has to be there before. so i think you should just not call notifyDatasetChanged() and when the user goes to the next view, the pageradapter loads the current (new) data. What about this solution?